# Cache manipulated images in PHP

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache

That works just fine.

But, the problem is when image changes but has the same name. My cache system recognizes that image has changed and deletes old cached file and creates new one, and then serves that new resized cached file from my own cache. But there is problem with either my system or web browser cache.

When image changes my script sends 200 OK header (for changed file)... But image preview does not change and response is 200 OK until i press manually F5 in browser. Then it sends once again 200 OK and changes image, and from then on it sends 304 Not changed (as it should). But problem is that I must press F5 to change browser cached image... I don't know why 200 OK does not change browser cached file...

Code:

```
<?php

// Image manipulation script

include("../../../Init.php");

if(!isset($_GET["File"]))
    return;

$sFullFile = urldecode($_GET["File"]);

$pData = pathinfo($sFullFile);

// Options
$sActions = isset($_GET["Actions"]) ? $_GET["Actions"] : "";
$iMaxWidth = isset($_GET["MaxWidth"]) ? (int)$_GET["MaxWidth"] : 0;
$iMaxHeight = isset($_GET["MaxHeight"]) ? (int)$_GET["MaxHeight"] : 0;
$bSaveAspect = isset($_GET["SaveAspect"]) & $_GET["SaveAspect"] == "0" ? false : true;

// Cache control
$sPathCacheString = md5($pData["dirname"]);
$sFileCacheString = md5($pData["basename"]);
$pLastModTime = filemtime($sFullFile);
$sOptCacheString = md5($sActions . $iMaxWidth . $iMaxHeight . $bSaveAspect);

$sCacheFile = ImageCache::GetImageManipulatorCacheFileName($sFullFile, $sActions, $iMaxWidth, $iMaxHeight, $bSaveAspect);

header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=2592000, pre-check=2592000, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: private");
header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime(" 30 day")));

$sLastModString = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", $pLastModTime);
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]) && strtotime($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]) >= $pLastModTime)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
    return;
}
else
{
    $pImage = new Image($sFullFile);

    @unlink($sCacheFile);

    if(GetFlag("ResizeMax", $sActions))
    {
        if($pImage->GetWidth() > $iMaxWidth || $pImage->GetHeight() > $iMaxHeight)
            $pImage->ResizeImage($iMaxWidth, $iMaxHeight, $bSaveAspect);
    }

    Cache::WriteFile($sCacheFile, $pImage->GetOutput());    

    header("Last-Modified: $sLastModString");
    header("Content-type: " . $pImage->GetMIMEType());
    $pImage->Destroy();

    Cache::StreamOut($sCacheFile);
}


/*

    Copyright (C) 2010. Determinanta
    http://www.determinanta.hr
    Part of WebSuite aplication platform. All rights reserved.

*/


?>
```

EDIT: SOLVED

I solved it... The problem was checking $_SERVER["HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE"]... I simply now serve cached file always if it is not changed. It took me whole morning to solve this thing... Thanks for all your input guys. Cheers.

```
<?php

// Image manipulation script

include("../../../Init.php");

if(!isset($_GET["File"]))
    return;

$sFullFile = urldecode($_GET["File"]);

$pData = pathinfo($sFullFile);

// Options
$sActions = isset($_GET["Actions"]) ? $_GET["Actions"] : "";
$iMaxWidth = isset($_GET["MaxWidth"]) ? (int)$_GET["MaxWidth"] : 0;
$iMaxHeight = isset($_GET["MaxHeight"]) ? (int)$_GET["MaxHeight"] : 0;
$bSaveAspect = isset($_GET["SaveAspect"]) & $_GET["SaveAspect"] == "0" ? false : true;

// Cache control
$sPathCacheString = md5($pData["dirname"]);
$sFileCacheString = md5($pData["basename"]);
$pLastModTime = filemtime($sFullFile);
$sOptCacheString = md5($sActions . $iMaxWidth . $iMaxHeight . $bSaveAspect);

$sCacheFile = ImageCache::GetImageManipulatorCacheFileName($sFullFile, $sActions, $iMaxWidth, $iMaxHeight, $bSaveAspect);
$sFullCacheFile = CACHE_PATH . "/" . $sCacheFile;

$bCacheNotModified = true;
if(!is_file($sFullCacheFile))
    $bCacheNotModified = false;
else
{
    if(filemtime($sFullCacheFile) != $pLastModTime)
        $bCacheNotModified = false;
}

$sLastModString = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", $pLastModTime);
if($bCacheNotModified)
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified");
    return;
}
else
{               
    $pImage = new Image($sFullFile);

    @unlink($sCacheFile);

    if(GetFlag("ResizeMax", $sActions))
    {
        if($pImage->GetWidth() > $iMaxWidth || $pImage->GetHeight() > $iMaxHeight)
            $pImage->ResizeImage($iMaxWidth, $iMaxHeight, $bSaveAspect);
    }

    Cache::WriteFile($sCacheFile, $pImage->GetOutput());
    touch($sFullCacheFile, $pLastModTime);

    header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=2592000, pre-check=2592000, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: private");
    header("Expires: " . date(DATE_RFC822, 0));
    header("Last-Modified: $sLastModString");
    header("ETag: \"" . $sImageMD5 . "\"");
    header("Content-type: " . $pImage->GetMIMEType());

    $pImage->Destroy();

    Cache::StreamOut($sCacheFile);
}


/*

    Copyright (C) 2010. Determinanta
    http://www.determinanta.hr
    Part of WebSuite aplication platform. All rights reserved.

*/


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is the browser. I have also tried to fight it with response codes and headers, but in the end the only sure way to make the browser grab the new image is to append a unique string to the url such as a timestamp. One simple solution is that when the image changes append the current timestamp in your html source as follows:

```
<img src="path/to/your/php/script.php?<?= time(); ?>"/>
```

Comment: Yes, I know for this workaround, but the problem with this method is that the file will never cache because it regards this src path as new image (because ever changing time() number)...

Comment: Agreed, that's why you have to have logic to decide whether or not to append the time() function or not. In your code you already know on the PHP side if the image has changed so use that same logic to decide whether to append the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting ETags (Entity Tags) in the headers of the images?

MD5 the image into a variable, then set ETag like so:

```
header("ETag: \"".$img_md5."\");
```

Comment: Sorry mate not sure how you're going to get around this. Lately I've been telling Chrome to not cache anything during dev-time and once I deploy I use a cache.manifest to force dropping of client side cache whenever I do a new release.

Comment: Yes... Chrome is awfull with caching... I'm using Firefox for testing and development. I don't know what to do... Is there any way of deleting local browser cached file?

Comment: In Chrome inspector you can hit the bottom-right cog and be given option to turn off all caching. Alternative is to open with new incognito window. Hope this helps

Comment: The problem is how to force any browser to understand that the file has changed.